# Zipped/compressed file aware delta uploading (cross platform)

Tags: windows, linux, compression, zip, rsync

So I am interested in a way (ideally cross platform) to have a zip file which is uploaded over annoyingly slow uplink connections (think ADSL) - where only the delta is uploaded (assuming a recent version is on the server and minimal changes to be uploaded).

Now rsync can work - with gzip rsync-aware support (ie you compress the file with gzip - but telling it to be rsync friendly) - but this is, well, a bit of a pain on windows.

Has this been solved before? or is rsync/gzip combo the state of the art?

(note that this network is asymetric - downloads are an order of magnitude faster - so not a bidirectional sync issue).

Comment: Not sure how you can improve on rsync, which already supports gzip compression by itself.

Comment: not improve - but its a pain on windows - and requires the file be gzipped in rsync friendly way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution seems to be "use rsync, even on windows"

Answer (score 1):

rdiff-backup is available [for Windows](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/FAQ.html#windows) as well, and pretty much intended for these kind of problems. Also handles binary diffs pretty well it seems. Only use it if it's non-mission-critical data, as the Windows-variant is not that well tested.

I use it for Linux, no experience with Windows whatsoever. It would probably be a good idea to compare hashes on local / remote location to be sure.

You have to implement some cronjob (schedule a job in the taskbar, don't know how it's called in Windows) to clean older files if you don't want incremental backups though.

Not sure if it fits your needs, but I think it comes very close and is definitely worth checking out!

Comment: yeah if rdiff/rsync is available "enough" on windows - it looks like it will work just fine.